# How many new array objects are created by the ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)?

Tags: java, arrays

I analyzed the following code and found that it should create 2 new array objects. Is this true?

```
 ArrayList.java
             public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
                    elementData = c.toArray();
                    size = elementData.length;
                    // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
                    if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
                        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
                }

            Analysis:
             elementData = c.toArray(); This creates a new array of object.

             elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class); This creates a new array of elementData.

       Arrays.java     
             public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
                    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
                        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
                        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
                    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
                    return copy;
                }

        Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
```

Here new array object.

Comment: I mean, anywhere from 1-3 depending on conditions. `Arrays#copyOf` isn't called except for (what I'd guess) is primitive arrays. Regardless, not sure why it's really important at all, there's very likely a better place to optimize than something like an arraylist copy.

Comment: Why do you think execution hits the `copyOf`?

Comment: As Rogue pointed out in case of primitive array

Comment: `c.toArray()` can't be a primitive array; Rogue's guess is wrong. It could be something like `Car[]` or `Map[]` in case of bugs, but are you actually supposed to perform this analysis under the assumption that `c` suffers from such a bug?

Comment: Thanks. user2357112. yes. As I understand, at max in the worst case it should create only 2 not 3 new array objects.

Answer (score 0):

i think it create 2 new array:

```
elementData = c.toArray(); - this instantiate new array
```

in next case created only 1 array:

```
if condition ar2 == Object[].class is true
```

then created

```
(new Object[var1])
```

or if false

```
(Object[])((Object[])Array.newInstance(var2.getComponentType(), var1))
```